# Multiple Session or Multiple User login in same website/webapp at same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies, authentication

can any one help me if there are `multiple user account` need to login in same website at the same time in same browser.

> Than what is technique and what i
>   suppose to do to maintain multiple
>   sessions / cookies @ page level or
>   Browser Tab level..

if i am not clear to ask..

i want just like gmail login that is you can login in gmail using multiple account at the same time and work with both account as well.. ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

It's all about not associating 1 session with 1 user.

Let me briefly explain that.

Usually you've a server session in ASP.NET storing some user values that may customize or place useful data like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["isAuthenticated"] = true;
```

What about:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["1182"]["isAuthenticated"] = true;
```

...where "1182" is just an unique user identifier.

Just store values in server session in some collection where its key is the unique user identifier of authenticated identity, so this allows a parameterized-by-unique-user-identifier access to session's values.

It's an abbreviation of a more mature and complex actual solution, but it's a hint of how you'd handle such situation.

Comment: @matias i used it but i cant persist value "1182" when page refreshed. !! so its very hard to do so...

Comment: What? Why you can't "persist" it?

Comment: look i just have two users 1182 and 1183 ok . now when user 1182 logdin 1182 need to be store somewher bz if we talk abt single user u can store it directly [1182][otherinfo] .. but when i talk abt multiple user there are 2x1 array [1182][info] and [1183][info] if both are logdin.. now both are in same browser with different tab "IF i press F5 on any of them.. i need to store 1182 at Page level... to get which one logdin is in which tab.. if i u cant understand just look at Gmail's "Sign in other Account...."

Comment: Hey, please write English (avoid chat-like lang...). But I thought my answer gave you a hint: you need to store a dictionary into each user item!!!

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help you, because I'm not sure what you're asking, but I had a scenario where I had to disallow concurrent log-ins using the same user ID, so as to not allow the same user ID to be logged in from multiple locations.  This might be opposite of what you're asking for, but here's my original post on Stack Overflow:

[When the same user ID is trying to log in on multiple devices, how do I kill the session on the other device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903574/when-the-same-user-id-is-trying-to-log-in-on-multiple-devices-how-do-i-kill-the/15939899#15939899)

Comment: Hello Mike, thank you for your answer. But this is not what i required!