# FormsAuthentication logout issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, form-authentication

I have a problem with this scenario using FormsAuthentication

I access a website with my login and my password, the system make login using FormsAuthentication. After that I copy the cookies from browser.

I paste the cookies in the other browser and click F5, The system authenticate the user and access, after that I make a logout.

I turn back to the first browser and click F5 and the user remains in the system ignoring the logout in the other browser....

how do I solve this problem?

Comment: A way around would be to stop concurrent user log in. BTW, how do you `paste the cookies in the other browser and click F5`?

Comment: You are creating your website or you are only accessing another website?

Comment: have you set the session time out for log out in web.config ?

Comment: 1- In order to "paste the cookies in the other browser and click F5" I use a extension for browser called "EditThisCookie", it's allow import and export the cookie

Comment: 2- I'm access the same website

Comment: 3- I set the session time out, I think the problem with the login authentication is in any wrong or something

Comment: @Kaf I can't stop concurrent user log in

Answer (score 0):

each browser uses its **own cookies** to check user status. then **logging out** of website in one browser doesn't affect your status in others.

so the only way left is **to avoid** logging in users from different browsers **at the same time.**

[Only one concurrent login per user in Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515716/only-one-concurrent-login-per-user-in-asp-net)

http://teknohippy.net/2008/08/21/stopping-aspnet-concurrent-logins/

Comment: ok, but is there other way to solve the problem? I was reading about Anti-XSRF token... Someone know this?