# Can ASP.NET Identity track and block same user multiple concurrent logins?

Tags: asp.net

Does ASP.NET Identity have the capability to allow me to track when a user is logged into a site more than once? If so, is it then possible to prevent the same user from logging into an ASP.NET site more than once at a time?

For some context, I have a customer with a subscription-based website. They are having issues with users sharing their credentials allowing others to access content for free. They want to first understand how much its happening and then at some point potentially configure the site to block concurrent sessions with the same user id.

If ASP.NET Identity does not have this capability are there any appropriate alternatives I can leverage?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/17518417/2145778

Comment: Yeah I saw that when I first started searching for answers to this question. But I ran this past this some guys on the ASP.NET team and they have reservations for doing this. I think their reservations centers around not knowing when someone logs out and TTL for sessions.