# Limiting user to one login session by unique ID in AuthCookie and checking against database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am creating a website that lets users run tests and hosts study content, I do not wish for any logged in user to be able to have more than one logical session. So essentially restricting simultaneous usage from multiple browsers or computers logged into the same account by invalidating any requests coming from any non-current/latest session. But I am not too sure on how to best hook into this with asp.net forms authentication.

I am thinking:

- Create a db table called ActiveSessions, with rows: UserID, UniqueSessionID. Store this UniqueSessionID in the encrypted AuthCookie on the client.
- If a user is not authenticated and logs in via standard login page /account/login etc. Create new UniqueSessionID and store it in the AuthCookie and in the ActiveSessions table respectively, overwriting any existing value. I presume I would have to decrypt and copy contents of the default AuthCookie forms authentication will issue, then create a new AuthCookie using this copied data and also insert my UniqueSessionID into it before returning it to the client.
- In the event a request comes in for which the AuthCookie holds a UniqueSessionID that does does not match the one in the database or the record is missing for the respective user, invalidate the session and redirect browser to login page or kill session and issue error for Ajax requests.
- Create some kind of scheduled service that cleans up records in the ActiveSessions table based on where User LastActivityDate exceeds some length of time etc.

Ideally I am hoping forms authentication provides some hooks where I can stick this logic in and avoid doing this with attributes over controllers/methods etc.

Also I wish to avoid using session state and its cookie entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar requirement. My situation was such that I had to make sure that user ID's were logged in from just one device at a time (Forms Authentication, by the way, not AD). When a user ID tried to log in to another device while still logged in to an existing device, it killed the session on their existing device while allowing them to log-in to the new device. The implementation I created has worked perfectly and so far, have found no flaws in the design.  I wrote up a solution on my original post on Stack Overflow:

[When the same user ID is trying to log in on multiple devices, how do I kill the session on the other device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903574/when-the-same-user-id-is-trying-to-log-in-on-multiple-devices-how-do-i-kill-the/15939899#15939899)