# Avoiding same login from accessing website content from multiple browsers

Tags: asp.net, session

I have implemented a solution for the my question. I need your help in identifying the problem if any when multiple threads are trying to access the content at a time. Before asking the question i have researched for similar question i found this link 
[when-the-same-user-id-is-trying-to-log-in-on-multiple-devices-how-do-i-kill-the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903574/when-the-same-user-id-is-trying-to-log-in-on-multiple-devices-how-do-i-kill-the)

but the implementation is slightly different from my code. Please have a look at my code. In Login page I have written following code in the login button click.

```
protected void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = tbEmail.Value.ToLower();
        string pwd = tbPwd.Value;
        bool isUserSessionExists = false;
        List<string> lstLoggedInUsers = null;
        /* */
        //lstLoggedInUsers.Add(email);//for detecting if user is logged in from any machine or not.
        BAL.UserDetails oUserDetails = new BAL.UserDetails();
        BO.User oUser = oUserDetails.IsAValidUser(email, pwd);
        if (oUser != null)
        {
            if (Application["loggedInUsers"] != null)
            {
                lstLoggedInUsers = Application["loggedInUsers"] as List<string>;
                //crntUser.SuspectedAttemps
                //lstLoggedInUsers.Add(email);
                foreach(var v in lstLoggedInUsers)
                {
                    if(oUser.Email.ToLower()==v.ToLower())
                    {
                        isUserSessionExists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!isUserSessionExists)
            {
                Session["user"] = oUser;
                //add authentication ticket
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                oUser.Lastname, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), true, oUser.FirstName);
                //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(oUser.Lastname, true); uncomment this when you want to createpersistent cookie
                string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies); // Hashed ticket
                // Add the cookie to the response, user browser
                lock (lstLoggedInUsers)
                {
                    lstLoggedInUsers.Add(oUser.Email);
                }
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                Response.Redirect("~/campus/training-room.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                //this condition will execute when a duplicate user is //trying to access the app with same emailid
                //and pwd as an existing user.
                errmsg2.InnerHtml = "duplicate login error";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errmsg2.InnerText = "some error here";
        }
    }
```

In My Global.asax i have written following code.

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        BO.User oUser = Session["user"] as BO.User;
        if (oUser != null)
        {
            List<string> lstCurrentLoggedInUsers = Application["loggedInUsers"] as List<string>;
            lock (lstCurrentLoggedInUsers)
            {
                foreach (var v in lstCurrentLoggedInUsers)
                {
                    if (v.ToLower() == oUser.Email.ToLower())
                    {
                        lstCurrentLoggedInUsers.Remove(v);
                        break;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if(Application["loggedInUsers"]==null)
        {
            Application["loggedInUsers"] = new List<string>();
        }
    }
```

Note: My application is about to go live. I tested this code by simulating different user concurrent requests by opening 3 browsers(IE/MFF/GC) in local machine. For me it is looking like everything is working fine. But still i need your valuable review.

Comment: You have some issues with lock (lstLoggedInUsers). You are iterating over the collection without locking near //lstLoggedInUsers.Add(email); The collection could be modified in Session_End or if btnSignIn_Click is running in multiple threads.

Comment: @stevieg: will it fix if i modify the code       as                                                          lstLoggedInUsers = Application["loggedInUsers"] as List<string>;
                //crntUser.SuspectedAttemps
                //lstLoggedInUsers.Add(email);
lock(lstLoggedInUsers){
                foreach(var v in lstLoggedInUsers)
                {
                    if(oUser.Email.ToLower()==v.ToLower())
                    {
                        isUserSessionExists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
}

Comment: @stevieg: Thank you for your answer. Your post gave me the solution for my question.